# Webhook OAuth - How do I exchange a webhook authorization code for an access token?

Tags: discord

I'm trying to use the [oauth approach of adding webhooks](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#adding-webhooks-to-channels) to channels within Discord.  The workflow is that a user authenticates with my application using OAuth.  Then I redirect them to:

```
ApiClient::API_URL.'/oauth2/authorize?client_id='.Discord::appKey().'&scope=webhook.incoming&redirect_uri='.urlencode($webhookCallback->callbackUrl()).'&response_type=code');
```

The redirect URL works because it does allow the OAuth'd user to choose a server/channel.

> When you exchange the authorization code for an access token, the token response will contain the webhook object:

I'm using the following request to try to convert the authorization code into an access token with no luck:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => env('DISCORD_APP_KEY'),
            'client_secret' => env('DISCORD_APP_SECRET'),
            'redirect_uri' => url('/discord/webhook-authorized'),
            'code' => $request->get('code')
        ],
    ]);
```

The response I get from the API is:

```
Client error: `POST https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
{"error": "access_denied"}
```

What grant type do I need to complete this request?

Comment: this actually doesn't mean you have the wrong `grant_type`, it means your code is invalid or your redirection URI doesn't match the code. (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2)

Comment: @PeterG That makes sense.  I am hitting the same URL as the oauth uses so it could be that I need to hit a different URL.  The docs aren't very clear on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',`

needed to be

`'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',`